# Angular 11 Route - How to land on expected nav-tab?

Tags: angular

I've a component with two cards in **cardCompoent**

- TASK LIST and COMPLETED TASKS

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((data) => {
        this.selectedUserId = data.id;
        console.log('data::>', this.selectedUserId);
    });
}

gotoInforContainer(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['users/' + this.selectedUserId + '/taskList']);
}
```

And another `info-container` component with following bootstrap 5 `nav-tab`

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <button 
            class="nav-link active"
            id="nav-home-tab" 
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#nav-home"
            type="button"
            role="tab" 
            aria-controls="nav-home"
            aria-selected="true"
        >TASK LIST</button>
        <button 
            class="nav-link"
            id="nav-profile-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#nav-profile"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="nav-profile"
            aria-selected="false"
        >COMPLETED TASK</button>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div 
        class="tab-pane fade show active" 
        id="nav-home"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab"
    > YOUR CURRENT TASK LIST</div>
    <div 
       class="tab-pane fade"
       id="nav-profile"
       role="tabpanel"
       aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab"
    >COMPLETED TASK</div>
</div>
```

Suppose a user wants to directly land on COMPLETED TASK(s) by clicking on **COMPLETED TASKS** link, How should i handle this ?

Logically stuck more than 3 hrs. And I've came across similar SO, but their solutions dont seem relevant to me (maybe a mistake on my part in understanding them)

Could someone help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current the tab from url param as,

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.selectedTask= params.taskType; //TaskList or Completed Task
});
```

Then base on `this.selectedTask` you can show hide the tab content as,

```
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div 
        class="tab-pane fade"   
        [ngClass]="[selectedTask == 'taskList' ? 'show active"' : '']"
        id="nav-home"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab"
    > YOUR CURRENT TASK LIST</div>
    <div 
       class="tab-pane fade"
       [ngClass]="[selectedTask == 'completedTaskList' ? 'show active"' : '']"
       id="nav-profile"
       role="tabpanel"
       aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab"
    >COMPLETED TASK</div>
</div>
```

Comment: should i passes `taskType` from task from parent to component to target compoent?

if yes, could you pls tell me how where is set and get that?

Comment: Its in the url  this.router.navigate(['users/' + this.selectedUserId + '/taskList']);
where i referred /taskList as taskType
Pls check your routing file for the exact param name

Comment: currently passing id only in `this.selectedUserId` is there any way add new property dynamically to use `taskType`

Comment: In your routing file ,
{
        path: 'users/:userId/:taskType',
        component: FgFormComponent
    }

Comment: nice.. let me try and come back @Tom

Comment: I could able to pass as you said. but its still not landing on active tab.. always land task list only

`[ngClass] = "[selectedTask === 'Device' ? 'show active' : '']"` i could even see what type being sent without any issue